# Meaning of 'if not fact' in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Would you please tell me what 'if not fact' means in this sentence? and also writing 1-2 examples of that would be great. Thanks.

> Fantasy or fiction (of which drama is one form) permits people to objectify their anxieties and fears, confront them, and fulfill their hopes in fiction **if not fact**.

Comment: They can fulfil their hopes in fiction even if they can't fulfil them in fact.

Comment: Stepping away, the sentence is circular: **Fiction** permits people to ... fulfill their hopes in **fiction**. Anyway, "if not fact" here means *although* it's not necessarily in fact (and it's not at all in fact.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "if not fact" are not used as a stand-alone phrase in your example. They are part of a larger structure, with elision or bracketing involved.

Consider the following sentences:

- These shoes are black if not brown.

We can parse the sentence this way:

- These shoes are (black if not brown).

That is, the sentence says that if the shoes are not considered to be brown, then one would surely call them black. We can repeat some of the words to make the sense clearer:

- These shoes are black if (these shoes are) not brown.

In your example, "in fiction" is the first context in which the author says that anxieties and fears may be objectified and confronted, and in which hopes might be fulfilled. According to the author, the second context in which all these things might happen is "in fact".

The sense conveyed here is that even though the activities are not performed in real life, there is some (therapeutic?) benefit in imagining them.

Comment: +1 for the Correct Details , but **I think** it will be good to state that "in fiction if not fact" should be written as "in fiction if not **IN** fact" which sounds a little better or idiomatic !

Comment: Usually it would be something like 'dark brown if not black' (at least this if not that), but I can imagine a 'black if not brown' situation; whereas 'fiction if not fact' are at opposite ends (just this and not that), which seems poorly formed, if not erroneous, to me.